# Mfc Dialog change color button

Tags: button, colors, mfc, dialog

Thanks for your help In solving my problem
I try to add a button that can change the background of the dialog to a different color i using visual studio 2010 but i think its might be wrong way to do that

```
    void PainterDlg::OnBnClickedButton7()
    {
    CBrush m_brush; 
    m_brush.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));
    return m_brush;
    }
```

Or it should look like this

```
    void PainterDlg::OnBnClickedButton7()
    {
    CBrush m_brush; 
    m_brush.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));
    return m_brush;
    }
```

both ways are not work for me
thankS in advance

Comment: The system cannot guess, what you are trying to accomplish. The `WM_COMMAND`-handlers do not have a return value. Randomly returning objects will not do anything meaningful. Why don't you start by decomposing your problem into its constituents: `1` Responding to user input. `2` Changing the visual representation.

Answer (score 5):

That is not so easy with CButton. (you have to draw all yourself in OnDrawItem, OnCtlColor)

A simpler way is to use CMFCButton.
Add a Member Variable for your Button (with MFC-ClassWizzard) and change it to CMFCButton.
Here an example to change the color button in green.

```
void CColorButtonSimpleDlg::OnBnClickedMyColorbtn()
{
  // add a Member Variable for your Button
  // Change it to CMFC Button

  // CMFCButton m_myBtn;     declared in Header-File  *.h 
  m_myBtn.EnableWindowsTheming(FALSE);      // (important!)
  m_myBtn.SetFaceColor(RGB(0, 255, 0));     // Change to your desired Background Color
  m_myBtn.SetTextColor(RGB(255, 255, 255)); // Change it to your desired Foreground Color
```

}

Comment: SetFaceColor works but not SetTextColor, and overall it looks awful.

Comment: Keep it simple! :) I am not an expert for color theory. SetTextColor works. Perhaps you have to invalidate and redraw the button in your example.

Answer (score -1):

Nvm found it

```
    int r,b,g; 
    r=rand()%255;
    b=rand()%255;
    g=rand()%255;
    CBrush myb;
    myb.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(r,b,g));
    dc2.FillRect(&rect,&myb);
```